# How to configure nginx to route to different IP?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

Providing it's possible, how can I use nginx to route traffic to a different IP address?

I have one domain and 2 different servers where I want to serve up content.  Main website is running on http://example.com  and currently works.  I have a forum I want to run with the URL: http://www.example.com/forum, but the forum code/files are on a different server, different hosting company than where the main website is running.

How can I use nginx to force it so when a user types in http://example.com/forum it loads the content from the other server, but to the end user it would be transparent.

Is this possible, if so what steps would I take to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you need to config nginx to serve from two different servers.
`location /` will serve from app server, and `location /forum` should server from the forum server.

[Digital Ocean Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)

```
http{
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com ;

        location /forum {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://forum-server:port;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://app-server:port;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }   
}
```